# How change the content with ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

First, sorry for my bad english.

I would like when one people click on the button "Page1", the controller return a renderpartial of the "Page1" and the same things for "page2" and "allPage".

My views is:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>Title</h2>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NameAction", //controller action name
"NameController", //controller name
new AjaxOptions //ajax options that tell mvc how to perform the replacement
{
UpdateTargetId = "ViewPage", //id of div to update
HttpMethod = "Post" //how to call the controller action
}, new { id = "FormName" }))
{
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="p1" id="p1"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="p2" id="p2"/>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="AllPage" id="AllPage"/>
<div id="ViewPage">
    //render partial view
</div>        
}
```

And my controller is:

```
public class NameController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NameAction(String btn)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        if(btn="p1")
        return PartialView("p1");
        if(btn="2")
        return PartialView("p2");
        if(btn="3")
        return PartialView("p3");


        return View();
    }
}
```

Request.isAjaxRequest equals always false and the partialview not update the div but erase all page

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: MVC2 or MVC3? Please cleanup your question's tags.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, I have removed the `asp.net-mvc-2` tag which cannot be used with `razor`.

Comment: Sorry to the tag and thank you for your correction Darin Dimitrov. thats works middle because, the solution with my "string btn" is not null but the ajax options not works :( if i test in my controller isAjaxRequest equals always false. And the partialview erase all my page and not update the div :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your submit buttons a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="page1" id="Page1"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Page2" id="Page2"/>
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="AllPage" id="AllPage"/>
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NameAction(string btn)
{
    if (btn == "page1")   
    {
        // the page1 button was clicked
    } 
    else if (btn == "page2")
    {
        // the page2 button was clicked
    }
    else if (btn == "AllPage")
    {
        // the AllPage button was clicked
    }

    ...
}
```

and if you didn't want to depend on the actual label of the button:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="p1" id="Page1">Show page 1</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="p2" id="Page2">Show page 2</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="all" id="AllPage">Show all pages</button>
```

and in the controller you could check against the value.

---

UPDATE:

Make sure that you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` script to your page so that the Ajax.BeginForm works and sends an AJAX request:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```